# AppCompatImageView set background android 17

Tags: java, android

I have vector icon and use AppCompatImageView in XML

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_location"/>
```

**ic_location.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="28dp"
    android:viewportHeight="28"
    android:viewportWidth="25">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M12.5107,11.0107m3.3369,0a3.3369,3.3369 0,1 0,-6.6738 0a3.3369,3.3369 0,1 0,6.6738 0"
        android:strokeColor="@color/mediumGray"
        android:strokeLineCap="square"
        android:strokeWidth="2" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M2.5,11.0107C2.5,16.5391 12.5107,26.861 12.5107,26.861C12.5107,26.861 22.5214,16.5391 22.5214,11.0107C22.5214,5.4819 18.0394,1 12.5107,1C6.9819,1 2.5,5.4819 2.5,11.0107Z"
        android:strokeColor="@color/mediumGray"
        android:strokeLineCap="square"
        android:strokeWidth="2" />
</vector>
```

**Log error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

it works on API 21 and above but not work on 17 API device.

when using **app:srcCompat** work but when use **android:background** app crash.

Comment: Have u added `defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }` in `build.gradle`

Comment: yes, i added this

Comment: You'll also need to enable support for vectors in non `srcCompat` tags by adding this line : `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`. try to add to your base activity or on your application class.

Comment: i added this, but crash again

Answer (score 2):

You should add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` to your activity:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

After that, you can set the background programmatically. For example: `image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_circle)`